# JBoss will not start with Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I am trying to use Hibernate Validator.  When attempting to start my JBoss I get the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name   'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
```

My environment is:

- JBoss 5.2
- Java 1.8
- Spring 3.2.11

These are what I have to work with.

I tried the following pom entries first.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>            
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

That did not work, gave the above error.  So I read that I could just go to the latest Hibernate Validator, 5.1.3 and would not need the separate javax dependency, so I removed the javax dependency and set the pom to version 5.1.3 of hibernate validator.  Same issue.

What am I missing?  Everything I read shows exactly what I have.  Is there another dependency I am missing?  I have seen some mention of slfj, do I need to have that dependency?  If so, what version?

Anyone have an example of a pom for the 4.3.1 or 5.1.3 that works?

Frustrating, seems like this should be very simple, so probably something really obvious I am missing.

Comment: The two dependencies are showing are incompatible. Hibernate Validator 4.x needs the Bean Validation 1.0 API and Validator 5.x needs BV 1.1. Which version you use, if you are using Maven or some other dependency management tool, then just specifying the Validator version to use should be enough (the Bean Validation API will be added transitively). Are you using Maven? If not and you manage dependencies manually, then you need both Bean Validation API and its reference implementation Hibernate Validator. In matching versions! It is actually easy.

Comment: I am using Maven.  I finally got it working with the following config - javax validation version 1.0.0.GA and hibernate-validator 4.0.2.GA.  I tried as suggested and put in 4.3.1 and left out the javax to be added transitively, no luck.  I may play with this later, but the 4.0.2 version gets me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working for now.  Went with this config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>            
    <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

I know this is not the latest, but the only one I could get working.  Could not get 4.3.1 or 5.1.3 to work.  But this gets me going for now.